# How does OOP translate to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around Rails' MVC system and its relationship to Ruby classes. In Rails, it feels like objects go out the window and are replaced by databases.

I'm working on an interview question right now and it requires me to create a website that accepts HTTP requests and returns responses. I'm not super familiar with JS and I like Ruby a lot so I've been using Rails. But I feel so limited by the database... it feels like things that I could do so easily in Ruby (e.g., look through a hash of objects and filter by multiple constraints until I got what I wanted) are so much more difficult with a database.

The interview question says I don't need to use a durable data store, but that seems like a big no-no in Rails. Does anyone have advice for how to change my mindset around this? (Or, in the short term, recommendations for other easy-to-use tools?)

BTW - I know this may beg the question, "why are you interviewing if you don't know this stuff?" It's an internship and I'm just trying to start interviewing as much as possible so I get used to the process.

Comment: I think it's a pretty common misunderstanding in Rails, that you have to necessarily fit everything into either M, V, or C, which isn't true. Even though Rails doesn't really have a built in or standard location for POROs (plain old Ruby objects), you can really put them wherever you want. Basically, databases do not replace objects, even though it is a common mistake to try and make them do that.

Comment: In Rails, and in most [Object Relational Mappers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping), each table is a class, each row is an object. The reality is eventually you'll have too much data to keep everything in memory, or it will be too complex for a simple file; you're gonna need a database. Databases can do much more powerful and complex things than you can code by hand. I would recommend starting with [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and also the [W3Schools SQL Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp).

Comment: I'm struggling to understand "objects go out the window and are replaced by databases." Objects can't go out the window; it's Ruby. Data needs to be stored somewhere, and databases are good at storing data. The intersection between Rails and data is ActiveRecord/ActiveModel, which is discussed in the Rails docs and any Rails tutorial--I would take a step back and bone up on some basic Rails stuff.

Comment: @DaveNewton That's fair, I don't think I phrased my question in the best way--after learning Ruby for the past few months and knowing everything is an object, I'm having trouble with Rails' focus on the ActiveRecord. It feels (as a newcomer) that I'm far more constrained in how I can interact with a model I create than how I can interact with a class I create in, say, a command-line Ruby program.

Comment: It's just an object that you can extend like any other (I mean, that's how it you build a Rails app). They're Ann OO view into the DB with a variety of query methods. It's not clear to me what you think is missing--you mention "looping through a hash and filtering by multiple constraints" which AR lets you do, but more efficiently because that's what DBs are optimized for.

Answer (score 2):

> But I feel so limited by the database... it feels like things that I could do so easily in Ruby (e.g., look through a hash of objects and filter by multiple constraints until I got what I wanted) are so much more difficult with a database.

Working with databases is challenging since SQL is a completely different paradigm. Instead of being object oriented SQL is based on tables and relational algebra.

Everyone finds it easier to hack out loops and create `if/else` constructs to munge data as a beginner. But its not really a viable solution at scale. Any time you spend learning SQL will pay off immensely in the future.

> I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around Rails' MVC system and its relationship to Ruby classes. In Rails, it feels like objects go out the window and are replaced by databases.

This doesn't really have that much do with Rails or MVC. Its rather ActiveRecord which is the object relational mapper (ORM) which is built into Rails by default.

In comparison with other ORM's ActiveRecord has a lot of magic. It reads your table definitions from the database and automatically sets up attributes - in other ORMs you do this explicitly in your model classes, a repository class, XML files or annotations. This magic is great for productivity but can be very difficult to wrap your head around as a beginner.

ActiveRecord is still very much an object oriented design - just with more metaprogramming then you may be used to.

> The interview question says I don't need to use a durable data store,
> but that seems like a big no-no in Rails.

This is a misconception. Rails is a very modular framework and can be used without ActiveRecord, with other object relational mappers (or object-document mappers) or even without any storage at all.

Models are also are not necissarily even persisted at all. They are just objects that encompass the buisness logic of your application.

Most beginner guides start with ActiveRecord as an overwhelming majority web applications use a SQL database*.

Comment: * based on my highly subjective experience.

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful! I didn't realize you could use Rails w/o ActiveRecord (or were "supposed to"). Someone suggested I use a lighter-weight framework like Sinatra for this particular challenge (esp. since I don't need a durable data store), and it's definitely helping me understand MVC better. I think I just needed a more gradual transition from pure Ruby to Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is probably one of the hardest things newbies face in Rails. In the Rails guide, models are almost always Active Record models (aka map to a database table). However, it's totally normal that not all of your models are Active Record models and / or need to be persisted. I think the term you're missing are Plain Old Ruby Objects (PORO) and Active Model.

A PORO could be anything from something super simple, a mapping to an API or composing several other (ActiveRecords) models together.

For example, you could have a versions controller which displays the latest version of your web app. The version would be determined by reading the SHA from the git repository, file or env variable. So it would never be persisted in the database.

```rb
class Version
  def self.from_git
    new(`git rev-parse HEAD`)
  end

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def to_s
    @name
  end
end

class VersionsController
  def show
    @version = Version.from_git
  end
end
```

Here are some links you might find useful

- https://www.codewithjason.com/code-without-service-objects/
- https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/build-chatbot-interactions/9781680507089/f_0047.xhtml
- https://thecodest.co/blog/hi-im-poro-2/
- https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/decoupling-rails-components
- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html
- https://www.codewithjason.com/extracting-tidy-poro-messy-active-record-model/

Comment: I didn't realize you could use (or were "supposed to" use) POROs in Rails. Thanks!